# Not able to change TextField Border Color

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to change color of the border of my `TextField` using a `BorderSide`, but it does not work.

This is my code below.

```dart
new TextField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.teal)
    ),
    hintText: 'Tell us about yourself',
    helperText: 'Keep it short, this is just a demo.',
    labelText: 'Life story',
    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.green,),
    prefixText: ' ',
    suffixText: 'USD',
    suffixStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
  )
)
```

Screenshot of the result is shown below.

[image]

Comment: You can use  focusedBorder and 
      enabledBorder decoration property. `var outlineInputBorder = OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87, width: 1.5));
  var outlineInputBorder2 = OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.indigoAccent,width: 2),
  ); =======> child: TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(
      focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder2,
      enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple)),
      hintText: 'Info',),)`

Answer (score 135, accepted):

That is not changing due to the default theme set to the screen.

So just change them for the widget you are drawing by wrapping your TextField with **new ThemeData()**

```
child: new Theme(
          data: new ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.redAccent,
            primaryColorDark: Colors.red,
          ),
          child: new TextField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.teal)),
                hintText: 'Tell us about yourself',
                helperText: 'Keep it short, this is just a demo.',
                labelText: 'Life story',
                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                prefixText: ' ',
                suffixText: 'USD',
                suffixStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
          ),
        ));
```

[image]

Comment: You can already see its work in action. It is just the theme color for your screen widget not being overridden

Answer (score 211):

The new way to do it is to use `enabledBorder` like this:

```dart
new TextField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
    enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.0),
    ),
    focusedBorder: ...
    border: ...
  ),
)
```

Comment: How different enabledBorder vs border?

Comment: @stuckedoverflow Intuition would suggest that `border` should act as a default value whenever `enabledBorder`, `disabledBorder`, `focusedBorder`, `errorBorder`, or `focusedErrorBorder` are omitted in the circumstances that any of those borders are used. However, it doesn't seem that the build method for `InputDecorator` references `border` at all. Either it has usecases outside of `InputDecorator` or it's a bug (being a field that is never actually used).

Comment: @Abion47 The `border` property covers all 5 cases as you would expect, for example, you can set the `borderRadius` and it would affect all cases. However it is the `InputBorder.borderSide` that must be overridden individually. Doc: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/border.html

Answer (score 133):

Well, I really don't know why the color assigned to border does not work. But you can control the border color using other border properties of the textfield. They are:

1. disabledBorder: Is activated when enabled is set to false
2. enabledBorder: Is activated when enabled is set to true (by default enabled property of TextField is true)
3. errorBorder: Is activated when there is some error (i.e. a failed validate)
4. focusedBorder: Is activated when we click/focus on the TextField.
5. focusedErrorBorder: Is activated when there is error and we are currently focused on that TextField.

A code snippet is given below:

```
TextField(
 enabled: false, // to trigger disabledBorder
 decoration: InputDecoration(
   filled: true,
   fillColor: Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
   focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
     borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.red),
   ),
   disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
     borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.orange),
   ),
   enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
     borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.green),
   ),
   border: OutlineInputBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
     borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,)
   ),
   errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
     borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.black)
   ),
   focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
     borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.yellowAccent)
   ),
   hintText: "HintText",
   hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: Color(0xFFB3B1B1)),
   errorText: snapshot.error,
 ),
 controller: _passwordController,
 onChanged: _authenticationFormBloc.onPasswordChanged,
                            obscureText: false,
),
```

### disabledBorder:

[image: disabledBorder]

---

### enabledBorder:

[image: enabledBorder]

### focusedBorder:

[image: focusedBorder]

### errorBorder:

[image: errorBorder]

### errorFocusedBorder:

[image: errorFocusedBorder]

Comment: enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,;Enabled Border solve my problem .i want to change default color to blue

Answer (score 19):

The code in which you change the color of the `primaryColor` and`primaryColorDark` does not change the color inicial of the border, only after tap the color stay black

The attribute that must be changed is `hintColor`

`BorderSide` should not be used for this, you need to change Theme.

To make the red color default to put the theme in `MaterialApp(theme: ...)` and to change the theme of a specific widget, such as changing the default red color to the yellow color of the widget, surrounds the widget with:

```
new Theme(
  data: new ThemeData(
    hintColor: Colors.yellow
  ),
  child: ...
)
```

Below is the code and gif:

Note that if we define the `primaryColor` color as black, by tapping the widget it is selected with the color black

But to change the label and text inside the widget, we need to set the theme to `InputDecorationTheme`

The widget that starts with the yellow color has its own theme and the widget that starts with the red color has the default theme defined with the function `buildTheme()`

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

ThemeData buildTheme() {
  final ThemeData base = ThemeData();
  return base.copyWith(
    hintColor: Colors.red,
    primaryColor: Colors.black,
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: buildTheme(),
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String xp = '0';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: new Theme(
                data: new ThemeData(
                  hintColor: Colors.yellow
                ),
                child: new TextField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: 'Tell us about yourself',
                      helperText: 'Keep it short, this is just a demo.',
                      labelText: 'Life story',
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.green,),
                      prefixText: ' ',
                      suffixText: 'USD',
                      suffixStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
                )
              )
            ),
            new InkWell(
              onTap: () {},                
              child: new TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.teal)
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Tell us about yourself',
                    helperText: 'Keep it short, this is just a demo.',
                    labelText: 'Life story',
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.green,),
                    prefixText: ' ',
                    suffixText: 'USD',
                    suffixStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
              )
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer by Jannie Theunissen (currently below this one) is the most up to date answer.

Answer (score 16):

```
enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
),
```

Answer (score 13):

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
    ),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey),
    ),
    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent),
    ),
    focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.orangeAccent),
    ),
    disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    hintText: 'Tell us about yourself',
    helperText: 'Keep it short, this is just a demo.',
    labelText: 'Life story',
    prefixIcon: const Icon(
      Icons.person,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    prefixText: ' ',
    suffixText: 'USD',
    suffixStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 11):

The best and most effective solution is just adding theme in your main class and add input decoration like these.

```
theme: ThemeData(
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
           borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.pink)
        )
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Inside your lib file
2. Create a folder called `colors`.
3. Inside the `colors` folder create a dart file and name it `color`.
4. Paste this code inside it

   ```
   const MaterialColor primaryOrange = MaterialColor(
       _orangePrimaryValue,
       <int, Color>{
           50: Color(0xFFFF9480),
           100: Color(0xFFFF9480),
           200: Color(0xFFFF9480),
           300: Color(0xFFFF9480),
           400: Color(0xFFFF9480),
           500: Color(0xFFFF9480),
           600: Color(0xFFFF9480),
           700: Color(0xFFFF9480),
           800: Color(0xFFFF9480),
           900: Color(0xFFFF9480),
       },
   );
   const int _orangePrimaryValue = 0xFFFF9480;
   ```
5. Go to your `main.dart` file and place this code in your theme

   ```
   theme:ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: primaryOrange,
   ),
   ```
6. Import the `color` folder in your `main.dart` like this `import 'colors/colors.dart'`;

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: CustomColors.primaryColor),),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have tried custom search box with the pasted snippet. This code will useful for all kind of `TextFiled` decoration in Flutter. Hope this snippet will helpful for others.

```
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 10.0),
        child:  new Theme(
          data: new ThemeData(
           hintColor: Colors.white,
            primaryColor: Colors.white,
            primaryColorDark: Colors.white,
          ),
          child:Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: TextField(
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            onChanged: (value) {
              filterSearchResults(value);
            },
            controller: editingController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Search",
                hintText: "Search",
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.white,),
                enabled: true,
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0))),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
          ),
        ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 40),
            child: TextField(
              cursorColor: Color.fromRGBO(25, 118, 218, 1),
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide:
                      new BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(25, 118, 218, 1)),
                ),
                focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide:
                      new BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(25, 118, 218, 1)),
                ),
                labelText: "Edit Phone",
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                  Icons.phone_outlined,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(25, 118, 218, 1),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

> Thank me later :)