# Flutter - Changing the border color of the OutlineInputBorder

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to change the border color of the `OutlineInputBorder` but tried inumerous ways and failed.

I created the whole Theme configuration through the `buildDarkTheme()` function but I can not change the border color to yellow

Below is the image and the code:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

const kBlackHalf = const Color(0xFF212121);
const kBlackLight = const Color(0xFF484848);
const kBlack = const Color(0xFF000000);
const kYellow = const Color(0xFFffd600);
const kYellowLight = const Color(0xFFffff52);
const kYellowDark = const Color(0xFFc7a500);
const kWhite = Colors.white;

ThemeData buildDarkTheme() {
  final ThemeData base = ThemeData();
  return base.copyWith(
    primaryColor: kBlack,
    accentColor: kYellow,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: kBlackHalf,
    primaryTextTheme: buildTextTheme(base.primaryTextTheme, kWhite),
    primaryIconTheme: base.iconTheme.copyWith(color: kWhite),
    buttonColor: kYellow,
    textTheme: buildTextTheme(base.textTheme, kWhite),    
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: kYellow)
      ),
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        color: kYellow,
        fontSize: 24.0
      ),
    ),
  );
}

TextTheme buildTextTheme(TextTheme base, Color color) {
  return base.copyWith(
    body1: base.headline.copyWith(color: color, fontSize: 16.0),
    caption: base.headline.copyWith(color: color),
    display1: base.headline.copyWith(color: color),
    button: base.headline.copyWith(color: color),
    headline: base.headline.copyWith(color: color),
    title: base.title.copyWith(color: color),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: buildDarkTheme(),
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String xp = '0';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: new InputDecorator(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(          
                  labelText: 'XP',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder()
                ),
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(this.xp),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

For more references:

[Not able to change TextField Border Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122394/not-able-to-change-textfield-border-color/50351946#50351946)

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17592

Comment: As a suggestion, i would be wrong as you want, but this border colors are based on your themes primary colors, it would be always black as your primary color is black. So try another widget other than "OutlineInputBorder". Happy codding!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add hintColor to your theme like this and it should change the OutlineInputBorder color.

```
ThemeData buildDarkTheme() {
  final ThemeData base = ThemeData();
  return base.copyWith(
    primaryColor: kBlack,
    accentColor: kYellow,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: kBlackHalf,
    primaryTextTheme: buildTextTheme(base.primaryTextTheme, kWhite),
    primaryIconTheme: base.iconTheme.copyWith(color: kWhite),
    buttonColor: kYellow,
    hintColor: YOUR_COLOR,
    textTheme: buildTextTheme(base.textTheme, kWhite),    
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        color: kYellow,
        fontSize: 24.0
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: it also changes the hinted text

Answer (score 115):

Since July you can now use `enabledBorder`:

```
new TextField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
    enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
      // width: 0.0 produces a thin "hairline" border
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.0),
    ),
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
    ...
  ),
)
```

See the [full documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/19694) for the new decorators

Comment: Yep this works, setting just the border doesn't work for colors and neither for the border size, but actually changes it to rounded border! Strange behavior that confuses me!

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I am using Flutter 2.5 version. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 49):

This is the solution for the mentioned problem use enabledBorder if the TextField is not clicked by the user and use focusedBorder if the TextField is clicked by the user.

```
 enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
        borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
      ),
 focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
        borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
      ),
```

Comment: `focusedBorder` will use the app primary color by default.

Answer (score 12):

You need to simply give the "enabledBorder" parameter in the InputDecoration

```
enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow),
              ),
```

Answer (score 5):

This will change the outline color of the button to blue

```
new OutlineButton(
   borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
)
```

Comment: this doesn't work and has never worked. Why even suggest it? Did you ever test it?
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18751

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `TextField` in `Theme` widget.

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: Colors.white), // set color here
  child: TextField(),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the hintColor property for the ThemeData, something like this:

```
Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: kYellowDark,
      hintColor: kYellow,
    ),
    child: Material(....),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most specific and easiest answer to the original question:

```
 Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.blue),
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Some Label'),
          ),
        ),
```

The primary color defines the border color for the OutlineInputBorder widget. Just wrap your TextField with the Theme widget and overwrite the primary color.

Answer (score -1):

To change the border color of a Card use the code below

```
new Card(
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
      ),
      child: Container(new Text("Text in a card"))
```