# Flutter EditText view Floating Hint in Material Design like gmail login(outlined box)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hello I beginner for flutter I want to make the floating hint material design edittext like gmail

Like that
[image]

I am trying this

```
body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all( 20.0),

        child: TextField(

          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          decoration: InputDecoration(

            labelText: "Email ID",
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        ),


    ));
```

result is
[image: u]

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the text field and typing to see what happens?

Comment: Yes it will go to the state you require when an Input is provided. It will be same as gmail as flutter follows material design guideline

Comment: if your referring some textfield design or theming, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122394/not-able-to-change-textfield-border-color

Comment: it working on focus can we fix it @Ashwin2000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using 'Stack' widget and 'Positioned' widget,
you can make it like below.

[image]

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Email ID",
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 10,
            top: 3,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Text('Label'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Label text supposed to do, what you want to do as you click on the button you would see "Email Id" like the label you showed.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution, floatingLabelBehavior does the job

```
TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
          labelText: 'Floating hint here',
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it simply by using `labelText` :

```
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        icon: Icon(Icons.send),
        labelText: 'Hint Text',
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
    ),
```